# How to get all region names i.e., Asia Pacific (Mumbai)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using **describeRegions** method from the **aws-sdk** package

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2020-03-11' });
ec2.describeRegions({}, function(err, data) {
 if (err) {
  console.log("Error", err);
 } else {
  console.log("Regions: ", data.Regions);
 }
});
```

As the response from the above code, it gives the json array with these parametes *Endpoint,RegionName,OptInStatus*

```
{
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com",
            "RegionName": "eu-north-1",
            "OptInStatus": "opt-in-not-required"
        },
        ....
        ....
    ]
}
```

How to get region names of this format like **US East (Ohio)** or **Asia Pacific (Mumbai)**

Is there any other method/function to call to get these types of region names?

Thank you

Comment: I know you are using Node rather than Python, but the answer on the duplicate question demonstrates the API call you will need. It should be relatively easy to convert it into Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return values from aws for your request not have region name. aws only give data.regionnames in code like (eu-north-1). i think you must make reference to convert this region code into region name like you want. make database or other reference use this link = https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html, and make new code to convert this. example

```
if (region.names == eu-north-1){
console.log("N. Virginia")
}
```

thanks, thats my opinion. cmiw